# Javascript class instances are not acting like individual instances

Tags: javascript, jquery

The code will be listed below.

I come from a Java background. I'm trying to implement classes in Javascript.

Using functions for classes, I was able to do this. But there is a problem. When I created different new instances of my LiveChat class, they appear to not be seperate. IE... The code is not independent of each other in each instance. As if they are pointing to the same data. Sharing the same code.

At the very bottom I initialize the classes when a button is clicked.

There are two classes, Buoy (the parent) and LiveChat (the child). I initialize the LiveChat.

For some reason, these instances are not separate from each other (ie...They are sharing data).

```
/* Buoy Class */
    function Buoy() {
        alert("y");
        var _this;
        this.$buoyContainer, this.$buoy, this.$buoyHeader, this.$closeBuoy;
        var init = function () {
            cacheDom();
            createBuoy();
            bindEvents();
        };
        var cacheDom = function () {
            this.$buoyContainer = $("#buoy-container");
            _this = this;
        };
        var bindEvents = function () {
            this.$closeBuoy.on("click", closeBuoy);
            this.$buoyHeader.on("click", toggleBuoyMinimize);
        };
        var createBuoy = function () {
            var id = getHoverID();
            var html = "<div class='buoy block' id='buoy-" + id + "'><div class='header'><button class='close-button img-button'><img src='images/buttons/x.png'></button></div></div>";
            this.$buoyContainer.append(html);
            this.$buoy = this.$buoyContainer.find("#buoy-" + id);
            this.$buoyHeader = this.$buoy.find(".header");
            this.$closeBuoy = $buoyHeader.find(".close-button");
        };
        var toggleBuoyMinimize = function (e) {
            /* If target is header not child */
            if ($(e.target).hasClass("header")) {
                _this.$buoy.toggleClass("minimized");
            }
        };
        var closeBuoy = function () {
            _this.$buoy.remove();
        }
        init();
    };

    function LiveChat(userID) {
        this.$userInput, this.$conversationArea, this.topMessageID, this.$loading;
        var init = function () {
            createLiveChatHTML();
            loadLiveChatUser();
            cacheDom();
            bindEvents();
            loadMessages();
        };
        var cacheDom = function () {
            this.$userInput = this.$buoy.find(".user-chat-input");
            this.$conversationArea = this.$buoy.find(".conversation-area");
            this.$loading = this.$buoy.find(".loading");

            this.topMessageID = this.$conversationArea.find(".message").first().attr("messageID");

            if (!this.topMessageID) {
                this.topMessageID = 1000000000000;
            }

            _this = this;
        };
        var bindEvents = function () {
            this.$userInput.on("input", setConversationAreaY);
            this.$conversationArea.on("scroll", loadMessages);
        }
        var createLiveChatHTML = function () {
            /* Buoy created in Buoy class */
            var html = "";
            this.$buoy.addClass("live-chat");
            this.$buoy.attr("userID", userID);
            //Buoy Body
            html = "<div class='conversation-area'>";
            html += "<div class='loading'>Loading...</div>";
            html += "</div>";
            html += "<textarea class='user-chat-input' placeholder='Send a message'></textarea>";
            this.$buoy.append(html);
            //Buoy Header
            html = "<div class='fa fa-comments'></div>";
            html += "<div class='profile_name'></div>";
            html += "<div class='user_online' style='display:none'></div>";
            this.$buoyHeader.prepend(html);
        };

        var loadLiveChatUser = function () {
            _callPhp("liveChatGetFriend", [userID], function (data) {
                var data = data.data;
                this.$buoyHeader.find(".profile_name").html(data.firstname + " " + data.lastname);
                if (data.activeOrNot == "Y") {
                    this.$buoyHeader.find(".user_online").show();
                }
            });
        }

        var loadingMessages = false;
        var loadMessages = function () {
            /* Load more messages when scrolled to top of live chat */
            if (_this.$conversationArea.isScrollTop() && !loadingMessages) {
                loadingMessages = true;
                _this.$loading.hide();
                _callPhp("getLiveChatMessages", [userID, _this.topMessageID], function (data) {
                    loadingMessages = false;
                    if (data.html) {
                        /* Prepending pushes scrollPos to top, so this is for setting it back to original scrollPos before prepend */
                        var firstMsg = _this.$conversationArea.find(".message").first();
                        _this.$conversationArea.prepend(data.html);
                        if (firstMsg.length) {
                            _this.$conversationArea.scrollTop(firstMsg.position().top);
                        } else {
                            _this.$conversationArea.scrollToBottom();
                        }
                        _this.topMessageID = _this.$conversationArea.find(".message").first().attr("messageID");
                    }
                });
            }
        };

        /* Update messages of open chat windows */
        var xhr = "";

        var updateChatWindowMessages = function () {
            xhr = _callPhp("getNewLiveChatMessages", [userID, this.topMessageID], function (data) {
                if (data.html) {
                    var isBottom = this.$conversationArea.isScrollBottom();
                    this.$conversationArea.append(data.html);
                    if (isBottom) {
                        this.$conversationArea.scrollToBottom();
                    }
                }
            });

            setTimeout(function () {
                xhr.abort();
                updateChatWindowMessages();
            }, 5000);
        };

        var sendMessage = function () {
            /* If enter key */
            if (e.keyCode == 13) {
                e.preventDefault();

                if (this.$userInput.val()) {
                    this.$userInput.val("");
                    this.$userInput.css("height", "auto");

                    this.setConversationAreaY();

                    _callPhp("sendLiveChatMessage", [userID, this.$userInput.val()], function (data) {
                        _callPhp("getNewLiveChatMessages", [userID, this.topMessageID], function (data) {
                            this.$conversationArea.append(data.html);
                            this.$conversationArea.scrollToBottom();
                        });
                    });
                }
            }
        };

        var setConversationAreaY = function (e) {
            //Below code is duplicate of textarea event on document. I can't get the document event to fire before this.
            //Because it is bound to the document variable. So I must execute this code to keep it updated.
            _this.$userInput.css("height", "auto");
            _this.$userInput.css("height", _this.$userInput[0].scrollHeight);
            /* Limit rows to 'rows attr' */
            if (e.keyCode == 13 && $(this).val().split("\n").length >= $(this).attr('maxrows')) {
                return false;
            }
            _this.$conversationArea.css("bottom", $(this).css("height"));
        };
        init();
    }
    extend(LiveChat, Buoy);

    $(document).on("click", "._triggerLiveChat", function (e) {
        new LiveChat($(e.currentTarget).attr("userID"));
    });
```

Comment: You're misusing `this` in every case. Every one of your objects shares the same `this`, which is `window`, because you're ignoring the `this` that is provided to your constructor.

Comment: Also the line `this.$buoyContainer, this.$buoy, this.$buoyHeader, this.$closeBuoy;` does absolutely nothing. You don't have to declare variables in JavaScript, and if you did, that isn't how you'd do it.

Comment: @meagar Doing that with the variables makes them global, doesn't it? Also, I read your thread, and am still a bit confused on how I can make the 'this' keyword be unique.

Comment: @meagar I read "In constructor functions (function calls preceded by new) this points to the newly created instance of the constructor."

Comment: @meagar Doesn't that mean what I am doing should be correct?

Comment: No, again, it does *absolutely nothing*. The variables don't exist at all, before or after that line. It produces a line with the values `undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined`. Making them global is the opposite if what you want to do anyways.  Function calls don't use the `this` in the scope in which they're invoked. You need to invoke the functions and give them the context on which you want them to operate via `call` or `apply`, or simply by defining the functions on `this`.

Comment: Use a debugger to inspect the value of `this`, you'll easily be able to see the point at which it goes from being an instance of `Buoy` to `Window`.

Comment: @meagar Ok. So I when I call the functions in both classes, I must do .call(this)? As an alternative, would I just replace var func with this.func? Should I just use this instead of var for everything in those classes?

Comment: @meagar Hmm my code no longer works after making those replacements :|